# Dúvida variational autoencoder 'cats_vs_dogs'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Estou tentando aplicar VAE em outros bancos de imagens do conjunto de dados tfds disponibilizado pelo tensorflow.
No exemplo abaixo eles utilizam o mnist:

https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/

Eu gostaria de fazer testes com outros conjuntos de dados como 'cats_vs_dogs' porém não estou conseguindo.

Eu acredito que somente precise adaptar essa parte do código para outro conjunto:

```
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
mnist_digits = np.concatenate([x_train, x_test], axis=0)
mnist_digits = np.expand_dims(mnist_digits, -1).astype("float32") / 255

vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
vae.fit(mnist_digits, epochs=30, batch_size=128)
```

Por favor, gostaria de saber como ficaria o código para outro conjunto de dados, por exemplo o 'cats_vs_dogs'.

Tentei dessa forma mas acho que está errado:

```
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = tfds.load(
    'cats_vs_dogs',
    split=['train[:80%]', 'train[80%:]'],
    with_info=True,
    as_supervised=True,
)
catsdogs = np.concatenate([x_train, x_test], axis=0)
catsdogs = np.expand_dims(catsdogs, -1).astype("float32") / 255

vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
vae.fit(catsdogs , epochs=30, batch_size=128)
```